# Batch File to Selectively Copy Files To an Identical Folder Tree

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 identical folder trees, let's call them `C:\First` and `C:\Second`, with many subfolders. `C:\First` has many XML files in many sub and sub-sub folders. `C:\Second` just has the folder tree created.

I want to go through all XML files in `C:\First\*` and put it in it's equivalent place in `C:\Second`.

But first I want to check if a file with the same name exists in the `C:\Current` folder (no subfolders there), in which case I will copy the one from `C:\Current` to the proper sub-sub-sub folder in `C:\Second`.

In other words, I want to copy the whole structure and files from `C:\First` to `C:\Second` but I want to take the latest version that may or may not exist in `C:\Current`. And, in `C:\Current` there are many files I don't care about.

Example:
`C:\Current` has these files:

```
a.xml
b.xml
1.xml
c.xml
d.xml
e.xml
2.xml
f.xml
g.xml
3.xml
```

In `C:\First` I have `a.xml, b.xml, c.xml, d.xml, e.xml, f.xml, g.xml` spread out in its sub-folders.

I hope I'm not being too confusing...

Comment: Can you post the batch code you have put together so far?

Comment: Have you made any effort to do this yourself? If so, can you post your attempt? If not, can you do so first before posting here?

Comment: Does `xcopy` help you get started?

Comment: I wish I kept track of everything I tried. But the "closest" I think I got was `dir /s/b/a:d` to get a list of all folder I have to go through. But I don't know how to then go through that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a problem is properly stated, the same problem description may serve as specifications to write the program. In your case, you have this description:

> I want to go through all XML files in C:\First* and put it in it's
>   equivalent place in C:\Second.
>
> But first I want to check if a file with the same name exists in the
>   C:\Current folder

The "But first" doesn't serve to write a program. You just need to write the first things in first place! For example:

> I want to go through all XML files in C:\First*. I want to check if a
>   file with the same name exists in the C:\Current folder in which case
>   I will copy the one from C:\Current to the proper sub-sub-sub folder
>   in C:\Second. Otherwise put the file from C:\First in it's equivalent
>   place in C:\Second.

The pseudo-code below is an example of how your original problem description may be translated into a program:

```
rem I have 2 identical folder trees, let's call them C:\First and C:\Second, with many subfolders.
rem C:\First has many XML files in many sub and sub-sub folders. C:\Second just has the folder tree created.

rem I want to go through all XML files in C:\First\* 
for /R inside C:\First with all *.XML files do (
   rem But first I want to check if a file with the same name exists in the C:\Current folder (no subfolders there)
   if exist "C:\Current folder\place here just the name of the file from the for command" (
      rem in which case I will copy the one from C:\Current to the proper sub-sub-sub folder in C:\Second.
      set properFolder=place here the sub-sub-sub folder from the for command
      set properFolder=change "C:\First" by "C:\Second" in properFolder
      copy "C:\Current folder\just the name" "!properFolder!"
   ) else (
      rem ... and put it in it's equivalent place in C:\Second. 
      set properFolder=place here the sub-sub-sub folder from the for command
      set properFolder=change "C:\First" by "C:\Second" in properFolder
      copy "the file from for command" "!properFolder!"
   )
)
```

If you analyze this code you will realize that the lines that get properFolder are the same in both parts, so a simpler method would be to get properFolder just one time before the if command.

You may use this pseudo-code as starting point to write your Batch file.

Comment: Aacini, I've been educated today. Thanks so much for taking the time for this.